# bootstrap carousel sliders not confined to my images

Tags: css, carousel

I'm pretty new to coding so it may be that I do not understand what I'm doing. I've tried every bit of code advice given on this website that seems to pertain to my situation and I cannot get results!

My carousel sliders are outside my images and I need them in/on my images. I want them the size they currently are so viewers do not have to scroll up and down to view my entire picture. You can view my predicament at http://mirandarodgers.com/lenoxhouse.html

Like I said, I've tried everything under the sun. Currently my code just says:

```
.carousel .item{
min-height: 525px; /* Prevent carousel from being distorted if for some 
reason image doesn't load */
}
.carousel .item img{
margin: 0 auto; /* Align slide image horizontally center */
position: absolute;
min-width: 100%;
height: 525px;
max-width: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm ashamed of how much of a hack this is, but it might help you out:

```
.right {
    right: calc(100vw / 2 - 374px);
}

.left {
    left: calc(100vw / 2 - 374px);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So to solve this I gave both the images and the `.carousel` a fixed `max-height` (I used `400px`).

```
.carousel .item img,
.carousel {
  max-height: 400px;
}
```

You vertical images will scale to a height of this value.

[image: screenshot]

You can play around with different `max-height` values and even have the `height` depend upon the screen size using [CSS Media Queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries).

Answer (score 0):

Whats happening is that the slider images are aligned to the sides of the actual carousel itself, if you want to restrict the size of the carousel set a max-width on it. This is because the size of your images cannot fit the width/height of the carousel and there isn't any code for resizing the `img` or the carousel. If you work on the resizing of your elements it should solve the problems you are having and try to find better images that are roughly the same dimensions or the carousel will expand/shrink unexpectedly if it isn't handled correctly.

I added the following to `.carousel` and it looked much better on the site.

```
.carousel {
    max-width: 70%;
    position: relative;
    margin: auto;
}
```

Also i would add an img tag with

```
img {
max-width:100%
}
```

And this

```
.carousel .item {
    max-height: 525px;
}
```

[image]

Comment: My updated answer takes care of the carousel  expanding/shrinking unexpectedly and all the images will resize to fit the carousel  without stretching. Play around with the values to get the result you are looking for.

Comment: Mobeen, the sliders did shrink, I assume because the width is set to 70%, but they are still outside the bounds of the images. I do not want that gradient to show. I want the arrows ON the images. I believe I understand what you're saying (set the size of the carousel) but it never works.

Comment: Mobeen, you are my lifesaver. Thank you so much!!

Comment: .carousel {
    max-width: 50%;
    position: relative;
    margin: auto;
    }

    img {
    max-width: 100%;
    }

    .carousel .item {
    max-height: 940px;
    }

Comment: Thanks, glad i could help, just another tip, i noticed that some images may not be centered or in the correct position so give this a read for future reference.  https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_background-position.asp